# refund a stripe payment as credit to the customer

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I am using stripe connect to accept destination charges from customers to service providers on my website. If i refund a charge + reverse the transfer, the funds are sent back to the customer's bank account. Instead, I want the refund to be in form of credit to the customer to be used in future purchases. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When a refund is initiated, the funds can only be sent back to the original Payment Method. If you do not allow ‘refunds’ and rather credit the customer’s balance, you could debit your Connected account for the amount and create a [Customer Balance Transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/customer/balance) for that specific customer:

1/ https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits
2/ https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_balance_transactions/create

Please note that the Customer Balance Transaction will only be applied to the customer’s next invoice and it does not work for one-off payments. Otherwise, you’d handle this on your end and track the credits in your system.